# Kubernetes Helm Chart: Initially create secret on startup

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have 2 applications each one has already a working helm chart

- App A - a backend application
- App B - a frontend application accessing data of App A

App B needs an API-Key to access App A.
When (initially) installing my apps I currently install App A first, wait until it's ready, run some API-Calls to generate an API-Key. Then i store the API-Key manually to a secret which is then used by App B.

I want to make the installation easier and thought if it's possible to do that in my helm charts automatically?

My first idea was to add a init-container to App B which (if not available) obtain the API-Key and saves it to a secret. Unfortunately it seems not possible to create a secret from within a pod (and my goal is to create the key only once, not on every startup)

Is there maybe another way I hadn't thought of yet?

Comment: What do you need to know to create the API key?  This doesn't sound like something Helm on its own could do, but a higher-level tool like [Helmfile](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/) could launch both Helm charts with a dependency, make the HTTP call (via a hook invocation of `curl`), and push the key into a Helm value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating and empty secret with the Helm chart, then update it with the init-container. The init-container must have a service account with the proper role to be able to "patch" the secret.

Something like the following:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: foo
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["secrets"]
    resourceNames:
      [
        "foo-key-holder",
      ]
    verbs: ["get", "delete", "patch"]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: foo
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: foo
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: foo
    namespace: default

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: foo-key-holder
type: Opaque

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: foo

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: foo
spec:
  serviceAccountName: foo
  containers:
  - name: foo
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
    args: ["patch", "secret", "foo-key-holder", "-p", "'{\"data\": {\"key\":\"<base64_encoded_value>\"}}'"]
```

Note: in my example I'm using the CLI to patch the secret. In your use case, you can replace it with a smarter script, that check also if the secret is already updated.

Comment: Thanks for this great idea. I'm implementing it now with a Job instead of the initContainer so it can be triggered if necessary (like on installation)